# How to print the order of important features in Random Forest regression using python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying out to create a Random Forest regression model on one of my datasets. I need to find the order of importance of each variable along with their names as well. I have tried few things but can't achieve what I want. Below is the sample code I tried on Boston Housing dataset:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
boston = load_boston()
rf=RandomForestRegressor(max_depth=50)
idx=range(len(boston.target))
np.random.shuffle(idx)
rf.fit(boston.data[:500], boston.target[:500])
instance=boston.data[[0,5, 10]]
print rf.predict(instance[0])
print rf.predict(instance[1])
print rf.predict(instance[2])
important_features=[]
for x,i in enumerate(rf.feature_importances_):
      important_features.append(str(x))
print 'Most important features:',', '.join(important_features)
```

Most important features: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12

If I print this:

```
impor = rf.feature_importances_
impor
```

I get below output:

```
array([  3.45665230e-02,   4.58687594e-04,   5.45376404e-03,
     3.33388828e-04,   2.90936201e-02,   4.15908448e-01,
     1.04131089e-02,   7.26451301e-02,   3.51628079e-03,
     1.20860975e-02,   1.40417760e-02,   8.97546838e-03,
     3.92507707e-01])
```

I need to get the names associated with these values and then pick the top n out of these features.

Comment: I don't think there would be any way that I know of. But I would suggest calculate entropy for each feature and highest entropy features would be the important ones.

Comment: @AnwarShaikh: You do get the amount of importance of each feature in some value using rf.feature_importances_ giving some values. We need to print the names along with its order.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First, you are using wrong name for the variable. You are using `important_features`. Use **`feature_importances_`** instead. Second, it will return an array of shape `[n_features,]` which contains the values of the feature_importance. You need to sort them in order of those values to get the most important features.
See the [RandomForestRegressor documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html)

Edit: Added code

```
important_features_dict = {}
for idx, val in enumerate(rf.feature_importances_):
    important_features_dict[idx] = val

important_features_list = sorted(important_features_dict,
                                 key=important_features_dict.get,
                                 reverse=True)

print(f'5 most important features: {important_features_list[:5]}')
```

This will print the index of important features in decreasing order. (First is most important, and so on)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I modified the code. Added my edits here. But my problem is still the same.

Comment: @ashishkumar I have added code to achieve what you wanted

Comment: @ashishkumar Sorry, typo in dict name in for loop. Corrected. Try it now

Comment: Thanks Vivek! It helped!

Comment: @VivekKumar Thanks for this. One minor detail. You forgot the f in your f-string function. It should read: `print(f'5 most important features: {important_features_list[:5]}')` ... for the noobs. We were all noobs once.

Comment: @Ike Thanks, I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
importances = rf.feature_importances_

sorted_indices = np.argsort(importances)[::-1]

sorted_indices
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add an explanation.

Comment: Please [edit] this answer to add the information provided by your other answer to this question and then delete the other answer. And still, I doubt that this helps or even works at all. To convince me otherwise please explain this code.

Answer (score 2):

You can print the order like this:

```py
importances = brf.feature_importances_

sorted_indices = np.argsort(importances)[::-1]

print(*X_train.columns[sorted_indices], sep = "\n")
```

Comment: I doubt that this helps or even works at all. To convince me otherwise please explain this code.

Comment: Also, please do not create multipe answers to the same question without explaining how they are fundamentally different approaches. One answer with different angels is preferred.

Comment: Hi Abuubakry. Can I ask you a questiön concerning your posts? Like, which one is the correct one? Or do both work? What is the difference? Your posts and silence together are currently giving the impression that you do not understand the concepts of this community, cannot appropriatly use the available tools and are unable to communicate in the language chosen for this community. Please answer and let me help you.

Answer (score 0):

By the following code, you should be able to see the features in descending order with their names as well:

Create an empty list

```
featureImpList= []
```

Run the for loop:

```
for feat, importance in zip(train_df.columns, clf_ggr.feature_importances_):  
    temp = [feat, importance*100]
    featureImp.append(temp)

fT_df = pd.DataFrame(featureImp, columns = ['Feature', 'Importance'])
print (fT_df.sort_values('Importance', ascending = False))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
# list of column names from original data
cols = data.columns
# feature importances from random forest fit rf
rank = rf.feature_importances_
# form dictionary of feature ranks and features
features_dict = dict(zip(np.argsort(rank),cols))
# the dictionary key are the importance rank; the values are the feature name
```